# Create FBSDKAccessToken from ACAccount

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, acaccount, acaccountstore

I'm using `v4.8` of the Facebook iOS SDK and developing for `iOS 8+`. I'm also using `v1.11.0` of the Parse framework

I'm wanting to get access to Facebook via `ACAccount` & `ACAccountStore` classes. The login works perfectly, but after I get access, I need to convert the `ACAccount` into `FBSDKAccessToken` in order to login to the Parse framework:

Here's my Swift code:

```
let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
let socialAccount = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)

let appID = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["FacebookAppID"] as? String ?? ""
let permissions = ["user_birthday", "user_relationships", "user_location", "user_about_me"]

accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(socialAccount, options: [ACFacebookAppIdKey: appID, ACFacebookPermissionsKey: permissions]) {
    (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) in

    var token: FBSDKAccessToken? = nil

    if let socialAccount = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(socialAccount).last as? ACAccount, let userID = socialAccount.username where granted {
        token = FBSDKAccessToken(tokenString: socialAccount.credential.oauthToken, permissions: permissions, declinedPermissions: nil,
            appID: appID, userID: userID, expirationDate: NSDate.distantFuture(), refreshDate: NSDate.distantFuture())
    }

    if let token = token {
        print("token \(token.tokenString) \(token.permissions) \(token.appID) \(token.userID) \(token.expirationDate) \(token.refreshDate)")
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(token, block: nil)
    }
}
```

I get this error: `error: Parse::InvalidSessionError (Code: 251, Version: 1.11.0)`

What am I doing wrong?